# Xcode 8.2 freezes on running the Objective-C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

My Objective-C code freezes the Xcode 8.2. However, the IPA file from the same code runs perfectly without any issue. The app isn't hanging or whatsoever, but only when I debug my code and everything freezes.

Please share if you have any information on this.

Thank you

Comment: Please add your code where you think it's freezing. As mentioned in one of the answers, it might or might not be the Xcode issue.

Comment: I bet that you are accessing UI elements from background thread. Issue is not related to objective-c and xcode.

Comment: yes, @NeilGaliaskarov i am working on background thread.

Comment: It is not recommended, UI elements are NOT thread safe. Call the main thread when you are updating the element